# How to obtain the properties of an Excel file in SharePoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i am creating a macro file with command buttons that when you click it, it will display the properties esp the last modified date and time of an Excel file uploaded in a SharePoint site. How can i do this using VBA. 
You're prompt response is very appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to get the vba/macro to run is to 'Open in Excel' from SharePoint 2010.  I don't think vba/macros will run when you open an Excel file in the browser.

I added the following code to VBA (press alt F11 to get the VBA editor open):

```
 Public Sub documentProperties()
      On Error Resume Next
      Dim oApp As New Excel.Application
      Dim oWB As Workbook
      Set oWB = ActiveWorkbook

      Dim propertieslist As String
      For l = 1 To oWB.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Count
        MsgBox oWB.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item(l).Name & ":" & oWB.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item(l).Value
      Next l

      MsgBox propertieslist
    End Sub
```

I then put a button on the excel sheet (Google search for "excel 2010 add button") to get instructions for adding the developer menu to the ribbon.

Comment: using VBA i can open a file in a sharepoint with this code:

`Dim wb4 As Workbook
Set wb4 = Workbooks.Open("https://ts.company.com/sites/folder1/folder2/01%20Project%20Documentations/INFINITY/Latest%20Reports/Infinity%20AKAMAI%20CDN%20Analysis%20-%20YYYYMMDD.xlsx")`

now can i get the properties of that file using the codes you gave? i mean where can i insert the URL and the name of the file?

Comment: I tried the code you added to your comment.  I failed to open a SharePoint excel file with that code.  However, if you are able to open the file and set it to the wb4 object that is of type Workbook, then adding the for loop from the code in my answer would yield the document properties.  You can try with a local file first to check the document properties.  Then attempt opening a file on SharePoint.

Comment: alright. this is noted. i'll try it. thanks Bill! :)